# Type inference failed. Please try to specify type argument explicity : Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

```
    class SetContentView<in R : Activity, out T : ViewDataBinding>(
     @LayoutRes private val layoutRes: Int) {
     private var value : T? = null
     operator fun getValue(thisRef: Activity, property: KProperty<*>): T {

     value = value ?: DataBindingUtil.setContentView<T>(thisRef, layoutRes)
     return value
     }
    }

    val binding: ActivityDogBinding by contentView(R.layout.activity_dog)
```

DogActivity.kt

```
    fun <R : Activity, T : ViewDataBinding> contentView(@LayoutRes layoutRes: Int):
     SetContentView<R, T> {
     return SetContentView(layoutRes)
    }
```

When I try to call in the activity as

```
val binding: ActivityLoginBinding by contentView(layoutRes = R.layout.activity_login)
```

Its throwing error as

> Type inference failed. Please try to specify type argument explicitly : Kotlin

in Android Studio. I tried similar in IntelliJ its working fine.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the `R` type parameter for your `getValue` method:

```
operator fun getValue(thisRef: R, property: KProperty<*>): T {
  ...
}
```